# What exactly is peer reviewing?

Tags: discussion

Okay, so this is probably an idiotic question but how exactly does peer reviewing an edit work? Do you have to be of a certain reputation to peer review edits? Who exactly reviews your edits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, just in:

I did some poking around the [privileges](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) tab and apparently, once you reach **2,000 reputation**, you can not only edit any question/answer directly (without a peer review), but you can also review suggested edits.

> These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit.

**Two votes** are needed to either approve/discard the edit. I recommend you visit [this link](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) for more information.

Cool.